# java.lang.StackOverflowError adding set to set itself

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

why below code is giving java.lang.StackOverflowError error

```
Set s = new HashSet();
s.add(s);
s.add(s);
```

What is the operation set performing internally and why it is calculating hash code every time?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.<init>(HashMap.java:1459)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySet.iterator(HashMap.java:916)
    at java.util.HashSet.iterator(HashSet.java:172)
    at java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:122)
    at java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:126)
    at java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:126)
    at java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:126)
    at java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:126)
```

Comment: you are adding Set instance in it self hence it call its method recursive without any exit condition.

Comment: Why do you want to add Set to itself, please explain?

Comment: @Prabhav, unfortunately I got this error while adding to it to confirm.

Comment: But I do not think, we need to add set to itself in real life.

Comment: yes exactly.. by looking at the implementation of HashSet, why its calling hashcode every time even though we added one element itself to find the right bucket.. understanding below answer sent from Paul Boddington.

Answer (score 3):

Your Set is calculating hash code every time because you use HashSet implementation which calculates Hash of each object inside that set and uses that Hash to make sure there are no repetition of elements. And since you are adding something to itself it becomes recursive without ending condition and fills up the stack -> stack overflow ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the same exception by doing

```
Set s = new HashSet();
s.add(s);
s.hashCode();
```

The reason is that the `hashCode` of a `Set` is specified to be the sum of the `hashCode`s of the elements (using `0` for null). In other words `hashCode` is equivalent to:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 0;
    for (Object o : this) {
        result += (o == null ? 0 : o.hashCode());   // <== This line is the problem
    }
    return result;
}
```

In your case, since the set contains itself, the call to `hashCode` in the body is actually recursive, and so a `StackOverflowError` is caused.

As for why `hashCode` is called at all, it's just how `HashSet` works. When you add an element, its `hashCode` value is used to determine which bucket to place the element in. This process means that `HashSet` has a very fast and efficient `contains` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Lombok and Java.

@Getter and @Setter instead of @Data .

Because @Data annotation includes @EqualsAndHashCode .

Example:

```
@Data
class Example {

}

@Getter
@Setter
class Example {

}
```